# Fetch Api - how to send PHP SESSION data to the target PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, session, fetch, fetch-api

I can't figure out why the Javascript Fetch API stubbornly refuses to keep my PHP session. Here is a minimal test:

##### loader.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'OK';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Origin session id is <?php echo session_id() ?></p>
    <div id="target"></div>
    <script>
        fetch('data.php', {
            method: 'get',
            credentials: 'include'
        }).then(response => response.text()).then((data) => {
            document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = data;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

##### data.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo '<p>Target session id is ' .  session_id() . '</p>';
if (empty($_SESSION)) {
    echo '<p>session is empty</p>';
} else {
    echo implode('<br>', $_SESSION);
}
```

##### result:

```
Origin session id is abe10f9c611066f6400b2ce3d0ee8f97
Target session id is a68e76bf1d5180d79d27a2bcfa3c462c
session is empty
```

I found several similar questions/answers, but none of them helped.
The suggested solution is to provide the Credentials option with '*include*' or '*same-site*', but none of them work.

I know that I can pass the session ID but if possible would like to avoid it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If the `<?php` tag in the `data.php` script really has spaces before the `<?php` tag, then session will not work, and you should have a `headers already sent` message in your error logs

Comment: @Shlomtzion: did you read the question? it says "I know that I can pass the session ID but if possible would like to avoid it."

Comment: @RiggsFolly: there's no space before '<?php' in the original script

Comment: Where does `Origin session id is abe10f9c611066f6400b2ce3d0ee8f97` come from, not this code

Comment: origin session comes from loader.php: <p>Origin session id is <?php echo session_id() ?></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the origin of the issue. This happened because I'm not in SSL (I'm on localhost) and sent this header from my .htaccess:

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; Secure"
```

I first checked my cookies with `var_dump(session_get_cookie_params());` and it returned `["secure"]=> bool(false)`

**Useful to know:**

**in PHP `session_get_cookie_params()` returns a wrong value if the cookie param is set into .htaccess**

This is because the function is reading the php.ini value, not the value sent with .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Is `session.cookie_httponly` enabled on the server ? If it is then that will prevent javascript calls from using the cookie (and generally speaking PHP sessions tend to be backed by a cookie). In the context of this setting, `http-only` implies "`http`/`https` allowed; `javascript`/`webassembly`/... denied".

You can probably see the current value with `phpinfo();`. or read more about it on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

Comment: session.cookie_httponly has the default '' value (empty). I tried to set it to false but it doesn't help.